# Restricting helm's fuzzy match to a substring of the candidate

Tags: helm, helm-for-files, fuzzy-search

`helm` sources have a slot named `match-part` which, IIUC, is the part of the transformed candidate that will be matched. In particular, the source `helm-files-in-current-dir-source` has the following `match-part`:

```
(match-part :initform (lambda (candidate)
                           (if (or helm-ff-transformer-show-only-basename
                                   helm-recentf--basename-flag)
                               (helm-basename candidate) candidate)))
```

This source also has `fuzzy-match` set to `t`. With `helm-ff-transformer-show-only-basename` set to `t`, I still see this source, when used as part of `helm-for-files`, doing fuzzy-matching on the full file name and not just the basename. For example, `abc` matches the file `aaa/bbb/ccc`. I had assumed `match-part` would transform the candidate `aaa/bbb/ccc` to just `ccc`, which `abc` would fail to match even with fuzzy matching on. What am I doing wrong?

The fuzzy match function which kicks in for the source `helm-files-in-current-dir-source` is the default `helm-fuzzy-match`.

Comment: I'm also looking to achieve the same thing: it's pretty rare that you want to match a filename based on the directory that it is in, though sometimes it can be helpful to see the full path in order to be able to disambiguate multiple matches.  It seems that the author of helm takes a different stance though looking at the support threads on fuzzy matching.